# Can't access web from local to vagrant host

Tags: macos, nginx, vagrant

This is my vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define "m1" do |m1|
        m1.vm.box = "centos/7"
        m1.vm.box_check_update = false
        m1.vm.hostname = "vagrant-m1"
        m1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.220.59.61"
        m1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
        m1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
        m1.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
        m1.vm.synced_folder "~/Working/source", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
        m1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "8192"]
        end
    end
end
```

I'm trying to set a static IP of 10.220.59.61. After `vagrant ssh`, I set up nginx and set up the virtual host as `test.local`. I added host and `curl test.local` from the vagrant box, and it worked.

However if I add a host from my Mac `10.220.59.61 test.local`, and then hit it from the browser, it takes more than 30 seconds before showing a time out error.

I tried to turn off all the firewall but it did not change anything. How can I get this working?

Comment: I found the solutions: ```sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1```